# @Html.ActionLinkにhtml要素を含めるには？

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
@Html.ActionLink("サンプル", "Sample", "Home")
```

これは実行時に、

```
<a href="/Home/Sample">サンプル</a>
```

という出力になりますが、タグの内部に単純なテキストではなく、以下のようなhtml要素を含めるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
<a href="/Home/Sample">
  <h2>サンプル</h2>
  <p>これはサンプルです</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

できないと思ったので、以下の方法などで代替します。

```html
<a href='@Url.Action("Sample","Home")'>
  <h2>サンプル</h2>
  <p>これはサンプルです</p>
</a>
```

---

仮にどうしても、 `@～`形式でということであれば、以下の様なクラスを自作して使用することもできます。

```cs
namespace WebApplication1.MyHelper {
    public class MyUrlHelper {
        public static MvcHtmlString MyActionLink(UrlHelper url,  string action, string controller, string text){

            var address = url.Action(action, controller);
            const string html = @"<a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>";
            return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(html, address, text));

        }
    }
}
```

表示する例

```html
@using WebApplication1.MyHelper
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">

    <!-- こちらは最初の回答 -->
    <a href='@Url.Action("About","Home")'>
        <h2>Sample</h2>
        <p>here is a sample</p>
    </a>

    <!-- 自作のクラスで対応（先頭行で @usingもしています） -->
    @MyUrlHelper.MyActionLink(@Url, "About", "Home", "<h2>Sample</h2><p>here is a sample</p>")
</div>
```